# concurrency memcached incr method invoke lead to cpu100%

Tags: memcached

```
@Test
public void concurrency() throws IOException{
    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder("127.0.0.1:11211");
    builder.setFailureMode(true);
    builder.setConnectionPoolSize(10);
    final MemcachedClient client = builder.build();
    final String key = "test";
    final Set<String> contains = Sets.newHashSet(); 
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pool.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int k=0;k<999;k++){
                    try {
                        long incr = client.incr(key, 1, 1);
                        System.out.println(incr);
                        contains.add(Long.toString(incr));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            }
            });
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    watch.stop();
    System.out.println("time:"+watch+",size="+contains.size());
}
```

//=================================================================

there is my code ,when i run it, my cpu up to 100%.

i want to use memcached incr method to in my project .

can anyone give me a help?thank you !

i'm sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally knew the reason。

because of my jdk verson is too lower.

[only jdk1.6,where the NIO has a bug.](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6403933)

when i turn to jdk1.8,it is running fine.